# How to listen CRUD events in spring data repository for Redis?

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

In my application I've used spring boot repository to CRUD data with Redis. It seems work as expected.
Other wish from my customer is to care about encrypting\decryping some fields. Redis consumes small data objects few fields only.

Sure I can manage this request inside of service which uses `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository` but I'm looking for more flexible solution. I believe spring data has equivalent for Redis like in similar directions:

- `EventListener`|`AttributeConverter` - for hibernate
- `RepositoryEventHandler` - for rest
- `AbstractMongoEventListener` - for mongo

Let me know the class name and library for my purpose, please.